# Android Unit Test get code coverage that how much covered the working functions from unit testing

Tags: android, unit-testing, code-coverage, jacoco

There is an in-build way to get code coverage by using "createDebugCoverageReport". but that's NOT I want. I just want something like how much I covered my functions of the project from Unit test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should setup JaCoCo to get coverage unit test
Prefer: [setup-jacoco-android](https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/setup-jacoco-code-coverage-with-your-multimodule-android-app-kotlin-a0f82573a1) or [jacoco](https://about.codecov.io/blog/code-coverage-for-android-development-using-kotlin-jacoco-github-actions-and-codecov/)

Comment: Thanks, But wanted to do that using inteliJ inbuild feature. and now its working. The issue was one of my testcase is always getting failed and coverage document not generating